# Node.js webserver CHUNKED encoding issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding

I'm trying to build a node.js webserver that listens on port 9000 and reads a js file when requested then sends the output on the response. This is what I have so far:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
        switch (request.url){
            case '/main.js' :
                fs.createReadStream(path.normalize('C:\\dev\\projects\\main.js')).pipe(response);
                response.end()
                break;
            case '/page.js' :
                fs.createReadStream(path.normalize('C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\page.js')).pipe(response);
                response.end()
                break;
            case '/page2.js' :
                fs.createReadStream(path.normalize('C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\page2.js')).pipe(response);
                response.end()
                break;
            default :
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Not Supported');  
                response.end();
                break;
    }
}).listen(9000);
console.log('listening on port 9000........')
```

I call the main.js file from the HTML page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:9000/main.js"></script>
```

When running the page, the first case in the code should run but all I get is this error in the browser console.

```
GET http://localhost:9000/main.js net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

I tried playing around with the headers in the response with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: What content type are you outputting from main.js? "text/javascript"?

Comment: Remove the explicit `response.end()` calls where you're using `.pipe()`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles The output from main.js is indeed text/javascript.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I did. Same behavior.

Comment: Also, does it show the response contents in the browser debugging tools?

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using express and express.static? Like, learning?

Comment: @mscdex I'm using v0.10.28 for windows and yes, the response is showing.

Comment: @Zlatko Yes, for learning purposes, I might convert the code to express later on.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with paths, I'll let you guys know, Thanks for the responses!

Comment: @Yuval So what was the issue and how did you solve that?